# How to monitor a program's Internet activities?

Tags: windows, hosts-file

I'm trying to figure out how a program communicates with its website. I've edited my hosts file so that their website points to my computer and set up a script that logs every time it's accessed.

But the program is still able to function at times and I'm thinking it's because it's going to another website I don't know about or a subdomain of their main website.

How would I find exactly what page on the Internet a program tries to access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specifically want to monitor access to a website, I recommend HTTPWatch (http://www.httpwatch.com/) or  fiddler ( http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ ). Otherwise , try wireshark or TCPView.

Comment: Fiddler at least works as an HTTP proxy - so unless the program supports and is specifically configured to use the proxy it won't be much help. I don't know how httpwatch works - but since it claims to only "seamlessly integrate" with MSIE or Firefox, it looks like it may be working too high in the stack to be applicable to a different program.

Comment: fiddler is what I'm looking for. Has very convenient features too.

Answer (score 1):

Use a net sniffer like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) Capture some traffic, Find the HTTP requests (or TCP three-way handshakes) then use "Follow TCP Stream" to see what exactly is happening on each connection.

Answer (score 1):

For just a quick look without going into a packet capture, I always keep a SysInternals program called TCPView in my bin dir. Fire that up for a look at where it is trying to go. Obviously for a more in-depth look at it's request, wireshark/windump is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

One of the peculiarities of MSWindows is that winsock.dll allows sockets to be reconciled against individual programs quite easily - most MSWindows firewalls (Kerio, ZoneAlarm etc) allow you to specify which programs are allowed to connect to which servers / ports. Its been some time since I played with these tools but IIRC Kerio certainly allows limited logging - all you'll see is the server/port it has connected to though but this approach would complement use a wiretap (e.g. wireshark) to capture details of the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

My favourite is  [smsniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html)